# Would one call this situation ironic, sarcastic or ...?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the similarities and differences between “irony” and “sarcasm”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26621/what-are-the-similarities-and-differences-between-irony-and-sarcasm)

Say I buy myself a CD of an album titled *Scratch* and the actual CD has a scratch on it; possibly by mistake. Would I call this situation "ironic", "sarcastic" or is there another word for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sarcasm is the *use* of irony (which involves opposites) in order to ridicule something or be funny*. An event or situation itself cannot be sarcastic, but people and the things they say can.

I -and many other folks- would call your situation of having bought an album titled *Scratch* only to find the CD was itself scratched to be "ironic". Although it is possible to [make a case](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/6618/6807) that technically it is only an *unfortunate coincidence*, I would defend my use by pointing out that the expected state of any new CD is pristine. It's not a strong argument but the exact definition of irony is hard to pin down.

Now if you took the album back to the store for a refund and the clerk looked at you and said, "You bought an album named 'Scratch', what did you expect?" that would be considered sarcastic!

<sub>*controversal. Some of us are just lazy and misuse both the word (by calling coincidece irony) *and* the concept (by making jokes we shouldn't).</sub>

Comment: :) Thanks for the very informative and entertaining answer.